# Why is the hopfield network a model of associative memory?

Tags: memory, theoretical-neuroscience

I'm struggling to understand the meaning of the term associative memory in the context of Hopfield networks. I'm not sure if associative learning is the same thing or a different thing. In associative learning, you have two unrelated items and you learn to associate one item with the other. In a hopfield network you have a partial pattern then you can retrieve the full pattern. How is this associative learning? Or are associative learning and associative memory different things?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE Liyuan.  In what context are you looking at associative memory?  What have you been reading which lead you to this term?

Comment: From a computational neuroscience perspective, I'm studying network models of associative memory including hopfield network and the memory matrix.

Answer (score 2):

An [Associative Memory is a synonym for Content Addressable Memory](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/15469/4397) or a memory which stores the result of associative learning, wherein an input item is learned to be associated with an output item.

A Hopfield network is a type of associative memory, wherein an input item (including partial, noisy representations of the original trained/encoded item) is an associated to a the ideal representation of the trained/desired/encoded input item.

For further discussion of Hopfield networks, I recommend look at the question "[What's the difference between a Hamming and Hopfield network?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/15744/4397)"